# Ayuda con un list y un botón

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando en laravel un sistema sencillo de alertas.

¿cómo puedo poner botones en cada uno los `items` de mi columna ingresada y que al apretar dicho botón al lado del `item`, me cambie en la base de datos en ese item la columna "read_at" con la fecha y la hora actual?.

Por el momento solo se como enlazar variables con la base de datos. Y no encuentro ejemplos que usan botones dentro de cada item de un `list`. Para que se entienda mejor la función de este sistema por así decirlo, es que me aparezcan la descripción de varios trabajos de la BD en el `view` y su periodo a un lado y una vez alguien termine dicho trabajo, pueda usar el botón al lado del trabajo terminado y que este registre en la BD el timestamp (hora en la que acabo), si el valor es null este se mostrará en la lista de trabajos del `view` y si tiene una fecha ya no lo hará. Espero pueda ayudarme.

Ajunto codigo del controller donde me agarra las variables

```
public function index()
    {

        return view('alerts.index', [

        'periodos' => Periodicidad::select('periodicidad.descripcionp','descripcion.descripcion')
                ->join('descripcion', 'descripcion.cod_periodicidad', '=', 'periodicidad.codigo')
                ->where('descripcion.read_at', '=', NULL)
                ->get(),
        'entregados' => Periodicidad::select('periodicidad.descripcionp','descripcion.descripcion')
                ->join('descripcion', 'descripcion.cod_periodicidad', '=', 'periodicidad.codigo')
                ->where('descripcion.read_at', '!=', NULL)
                ->get()
        ]);
}
```

y por otra parte el codigo del view:

```
<ul class="list-group">


            @foreach($periodos as $periodo)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$periodo->descripcion}}
            {{$periodo->descripcionp}}
   </li>
@endforeach
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general, tienes que crear un formulario dentro del < li > por ejemplo:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    {{$periodo->descripcion}}
    {{$periodo->descripcionp}}
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route("Periodicidad.update", [$periodo->id]) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <input type="submit" value="Terminado">
    </form>
</li>
```

Luego en el controlador en la función update actualizaras en la base de datos el campo read_at.

Espero haberte orientado.

Comment: Muchas gracias acabo de usarlo y me deja poner el boton pero ahora me sale error 404 page not found al apretar en el boton ¿sabes a que se puede deber ? Te muestro el codigo. Esto lo puse en el web.php `Route::put('Alertas/{id}', 'Alerts@update' )->name('alerts.update');` y esto en el controlador  `public function update($id)
    {
      $cambiar = pamatrizinfoperio::findOrFail($id);
      $cambiar->read_at = freshTimestamp();

       
    }` Tal Vez lo estoy usando mal, en el view lo puse como tu lo pusiste, te mando muchos saludos @Mundoco

Comment: revisa con php artisan route:list que si salga la ruta que pusiste o que si exista el controlador Alerts